# BREAKING DOWN AN INCEMENTAL COLUMN IN SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an Employee table with the following columns `EmpId, Emp_Name` and `Emp_Salary`. So the Emp_Salary is an incremental column where each cell is that particular employer's salary plus preceding salaries.

Example: Emp_Salary (1000, 3000, 4000, 7000, 8000)

How do I write code to get a new column which gives the individual salaries (1000, 2000, 1000, 3000, 1000), which doesn't sum previous salaries.

Expected output:

| Emp_Salary | Individual_Salary |
| --- | --- |
| 1000 | 1000 |
| 3000 | 2000 |
| 4000 | 1000 |
| 7000 | 3000 |
| 8000 | 1000 |

Comment: Please tag the RDBMS! Either SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle...

Comment: Do not unnecessarily edit a reply to tell your backend. Add the tag here. Reply already covers for MS SQL Server. I added the tag for you.

Comment: Please post your existing query. We don't know how `Emp_Salary` is computed or what data type it is and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't tag your database but this would work with many of them (ie: postgreSQL, MS SQL server ...):

```
select 
emp_salary - lag(emp_salary,1,0) over (order by emp_salary)
from employees;
```

However, I must note that your table definition doesn't make any sense.

Comment: SQL Server working fiddle : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a7a6de86e77bf42c2db391f9c2996a30

Comment: Sorry....I am working in SQL Server. I though my definition was well explained: Table Name: Employee, Columns: (EmpId, Emp_Name and Emp_Salary).  Emp_Salary contains salaries but in incremental order thus instead of 1000, 2000, 1000, 3000, 1000 for individual rows,  it is 1000, 3000, 4000, 7000 and 8000. Thanks for your answer. It worked.

Comment: No, I didn't mean your explanation was lacking. I meant you shouldn't use such a design.

Comment: I wanna work on a covid dataset but the column of new cases is incremental but I wanted a way to extract the values for each row. So i just used this Employee table as an example. The reasons why they would opt for an incremental column beats me. But it made me figure out a solution by asking here so in that light its good I came across that dataset with poor design choice. Hahaha. Thanks again for your help. This is a great community. I do not know why I hadn't used it when I was doing my masters and needed help with SQL and Python. I would wanna know how to do it in Python but another day